# Getting an class to show when item is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, gallery

I'm trying to create a gallery from scratch so that I can learn how it's done. So far I've managed to get my gallery working the way I want execept that when a thumbnail is active it has to have a white overlay and that is where I'm having a problem.

My JS

```
$(".galImg").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#feature').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
});
```

My html

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <a class="galImg active" rel="http://s25.postimg.org/keaisiflb/mini_brown_fairy.jpg" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/keaisiflb/mini_brown_fairy.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="galImg" rel="http://s25.postimg.org/xwhf4srqn/mini_blue_fairy.jpg" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/xwhf4srqn/mini_blue_fairy.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="galImg" rel="http://s25.postimg.org/smcgdi7hr/mini_purple_fairy.jpg" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/smcgdi7hr/mini_purple_fairy.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="feature" class="main-image">
    <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/keaisiflb/mini_brown_fairy.jpg">
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.active{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 077;
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t8ut05y8/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `removeClass` and `addClass`:

```
$(".galImg").click(function () {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#feature').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
    $('.galImg').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/t8ut05y8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You have to use opacity value from 0 to 1, for making faint use values near to 0. see below css

```
.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And use below jquery to apply and remove `active` class
jQuery :

```
$(".galImg").click(function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#feature').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t8ut05y8/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".galImg").click(function() {
// first you remove all active class if theres some so you grab the parent
var parent = $(this).parent,
    image = $(this).attr("rel");
parent.children('.galImg").removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
var 
$('#feature').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

For JS:

```
$(".galImg").click(function () {
        var image = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('#feature').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
        $('.galImg').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

For css:

```
    .active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.thumbnails img{
    width: 20%;
}
```